# wso2 routing by url

Tags: wso2, esb

So i'm trying to do some works on wso2 and i want to implement an ESB that depending the url calls differents webservices.

So if i have something like that:

- SOME_URL/esb/serviceA .. the switch should detect that on the url i have the keyword serviceA, so it should call the endpoint "Service A"

The same should happen to Service B

- SOME_URL/esb/serviceA .. should call the endpoint "Service B"

Code avaiable:

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/esb">
<inSequence>
    <property description="Get Routing" expression="json-eval($.esb)" name="Action" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <switch description="" source="get-property('esb')">
        <case regex=".*/serviceA">
            <call>
                <endpoint key="serviceA"/>
            </call>
        </case>
        <case regex=".*/serviceB">                
            <call>
                <endpoint key="serviceB"/>
            </call>
        </case>
        <default/>
    </switch>            
</inSequence>
```

As you can see i have a regular expression to match the url "*.Service" and i also have a property to help me routing the request. For some reason when i type someurl/esb/serviceA or someurl/esb/serviceB i get: "API No matching resource was found for the request" .. so i guess the problem is related to the regular expression. On the wso2 documentation i only saw a topic abouting routing based on a request field and not on the url .. so i'm a little bit lost

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way of implementing API's in wso2 ESB, As your URL changes so rather than using switch mediator and making things complicated i would suggest use "URL-Mapping", below is the code snippet, hope it helps.

```
  <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test_APi" context="/esb">
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/serviceA">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="ServiceAINSeq" expression="."/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/serviceB">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="ServiceBINSeq" expression="."/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```